How to avoid using a private key with Safe.init() in Safe Global Protocol Kit?
Alternatively, I'm trying to use window.ethereum
 const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
 await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
 const signer = provider.getSigner();

 const protocolKitOwner1 = await Safe.init({
    provider: RPC_URL,
    signer,
    safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS,
 });

As a result, I'm getting an error:
TypeError: invalid private key (argument="privateKey", value="[ REDACTED ]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.13.1)

I am concerned about the placing of the private key in the .env
Thanks for any advice you can give!

https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit/guides/migrate-to-v4
// new
await Safe.init({
   provider: window.ethereum, // Or any compatible EIP-1193 provider
   signer: "0xSignerAddressOrPrivateKey", // Signer address or private key
   safeAddress: '0xSafeAddress'
   ...
})

// ...or...
await Safe.init({
   provider: 'http://rpc.url', // Or websocket
   signer: '0xPrivateKey' // Signer private key
   safeAddress: '0xSafeAddress'
   ...
})


When I first used this technology, it wasn't obvious that I needed to refer to the migration section of the documentation for complete information.

When I try to use Safe.init() in server-side, since I'm integrated it with frame.js, I want to let ppl can sign the safe tx via frame, but I cannot access window.ethereum. Any suggestion?
export const POST = frames(async (ctx) => {

const { senderAddress, safeAddress, to, value, data } = ctx.searchParams;
if (!senderAddress || !safeAddress || !to || !value || !data) {
throw new Error("Missing required parameters");
}
try {
const protocolKit = await Safe.init({
provider: window?.ethereum,
signer: senderAddress,
safeAddress: safeAddress,
})

You’ve added this as an answer, but it’s actually a separate question. Please delete it from here and repost it as a question, ensuring you use proper formatting.
